# HTML Form Override Method GET

Tags: html, forms

if we not set method attribute on `<form>` and then submit then it will use method `GET`

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="foo" value="test" />
</form>
```

How to change the default method into `POST` if we not set the method attribute?

Comment: What is wrong with setting the method attribute?

Comment: @Quentin What do you mean by what is wrong?

Comment: why are you not using method="POST"?

Comment: The correct way to set the method for a form is to use the method attribute. Why are you rejecting that as an option in your question?

Comment: @PhilippMehrwald for less typing, i want to change the default method. So i will not type `method="post"` too many times.

Comment: @GusDeCooL "So i will not type method="post" too many times" lol'd

Comment: :-D this thread took you more time than adding this attribute 50 times.

Comment: @PhilippMehrwald Hahhahaha... LOL...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no common way to avoid that. If you want to avoid it really bad, you might want to use a templating language or so that then compiles to HTML.

Comment: yes, templating language can be also the solution. But i wondering, maybe there is already some way to do it in pure HTML way.

Comment: +1 for using a template. You are very probably doing something wrong if you have that many forms on your site and are typing the HTML for them all manually.

Comment: There is no HTML way to set a default method for all forms.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you Quention, that's what i want to make sure. If there is no pure HTML Way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to change the default behaviour of the `<form>`-Tag. You could either type method="post" (or use the search&replace-feature of your editor to replace `<form` with `<form method='post'` or use a JavaScript, that puts this attribute everywhere (which would not work on browsers with JavaScript disabled). You could also use a server-side language like PHP to do the replacing, if your pages are generated.

Answer (score -3):

You shouldn't, [spec say's get is the default method](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) and you can't really change that...

If you want to be lazy at the expense of best practices & common decency you can use jQuery to do it like so:

```
$("form").attr("method","post");
```

but that's just really lazy, and I would never ever suggest to use it. It's not too much work to code it right in the first place with `method="post"`

The major issues with this method is that JS **MUST** be activated for the form to submit properly, since your server is expecting `POST` data, it probably wouldn't know what to do with `GET` data if the JS failed, unless you set it up to get both, which is probably just as much work as writing the proper html in the first place...

Comment: What if someone submits before the script has run? What if JS is turned off?

Comment: I totally agree, do everything you can do in html (except styling of course) using JS to fix your HTML code is very bad